# When should cdot be placed in brackets?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I was writing a document where I wanted to write the unit Newton meter. My code initially looked like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[M=10\,\text{N}\cdot\text{m}\]
\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

it is clearly visible that the spacing between "N", the cdot and "m" is too large -- it doesn't quite look like it belongs together (which it does since it's one unit).

I then looked at the [Wikipedia page for newton meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-metre) and they used the following code<sup>1</sup>:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[M=10\,\text{N}{\cdot}\text{m}\]
\end{document}
```

it's the same except the `\cdot` is placed in curly brackets like this `{\cdot}`. It renders like this:

[image]

which looks a lot better in this situation.

My question basically is: Why does placing a `\cdot` in brackets reduce/remove the space around it? Should this be used in any situation other than multiplying units?

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not the exact code that the Wikipedia article uses (for example they also placed the `\text{N}` in brackets and used `\mathrm{m}` instead of `\text{m}`) but it gives the same result.

Comment: You should use `siunitx`. Anyway; `\text` is wrong in this context and should be `\mathrm`.

Comment: If you load the `siunitx` package, you could replace `10\,\text{N}{\cdot}\text{m}` with `\qty{10}{\newton\meter}`. Note that the SI does *not* recommend placing `\cdot` between (multiplicative) units.

Comment: Do please take note of the fact that LaTeX-like technical notation that may be in use on some randomly chosen Wikipedia page should *not* be taken to possess  model character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the same with `1+2` and `1{+}2`

An expression surrounded with `{}` is a "`\mathord`" so an ordinary symbol that is given no additional space by TeX. Conversely by default + (and `\cdot`) is a `\mathbin` by default: that is, a binary operator and gets a medium math space added either side if used in infix position between two mathord symbols.

Comment: note here I'm just addressing the use of `{}` to affect spacing. units are better set with `siuinitx` to get a uniform setting without such micro-adjustements on each expression, and `\text` is designed to pick up the font current outside the math, so not suitable here.